# Angular FormData filename encoding

Tags: angularjs

I'm having problems with angular file upload filename ecoding.

Example: uploading file `žžž.txt`. Result: `Å¾Å¾Å¾.txt`

Relevent Html form parts:

```
<form id="fileupload"
action="/filestore/services/process/upload"
method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data"
data-ng-app="MyApp"
data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController"
data-file-upload="options"


<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled" file-change="uploadFile($event, files)">
```

File controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function($event, files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    console.log(file);
    console.log(data);
    data.append('file-0', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: uploadUrl,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            $scope.reload();
        }
    });
};
```

File object (printed by console.log(file)):

```
lastModified 1467975647307
lastModifiedDate Date {Fri Jul 08 2016 14:00:47 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)}
name "žžž.txt"
size 7
type "text/plain"
```

Post request data body:

```
Source
-----------------------------2159279631001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-0"; filename="Å¾Å¾Å¾.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


-----------------------------2159279631001--
```

As you can see from data/code, FormData is forming data object with incorrect filename, while File object itself is correct...any ideas why is that? How should I solve this?

Edit:

Request headers:

```
Content-Type multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9275749615024
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
X-Requested-Wit XMLHttpRequest
```

Response headers:

```
Content-Length 337
Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Most probably this is the problem of character set.

Comment: The answer posted here might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512585/2720591

Answer (score 0):

You should set the contentType and encoding on your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
        url: uploadUrl,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        processData: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            $scope.reload();
        }
    });
```

note that you should change charset
To the specific charset you are using and wich contains ž

Also if you are using a backend. Make sure it uses the correct character encoding as well

**UTF-8 should do the trick**

Comment: Don't think I can change ajax  request content type, since it's set when sending request. Request header content type: `multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9275749615024`. Response header is utf8: `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Just copy what you see in Request header and place it in contentType: pasteyourcopy then add charset=utf-8
So for you it would be "multipart/form-data; boundary=9275749615024; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the right idea to hardcode header type like that, since boundary is changing, not staying the same with each request.

Comment: im not saying you have to hardcode it. You can also dynamically check which header is required for a particular file. But I believe this should fix the problem you are having

Comment: How would you suggest I check which header is needed?